# Is there an R function like Support but with more capacity, because support only have capacity for 200 samples and I need more

Tags: r, sampling

```
base100 <- base[sample(1:nrow(base), 100, replace = F),]
base100 <- data.frame(base100)

P <- base100$DIAS

library(TeachingSampling)

N <- length(P)
N
n <- 2
Support(N, n, P)
```

"But it doesn´t give a result because it´s too much data"

Comment: What is `base`? Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so someone can help test your code and suggest a new result.

Comment: It's worth trying to do the math on exactly how many combinations this is going to result in. Sometimes these kinds of "every combination" functions can give billions of results.

Comment: Please, read [mcve] and precise the libraries needed to execute your code